# Flink history server not showing running applications

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to configure flink history server. I have followed the flink document [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/historyserver.html). I am able to bring up the history server but could only see the completed jobs, not the running jobs. Am I missing something or is it just the completed jobs are displayed in the history server. Kindly help.

**Jobs currently in cluster :**

localhost:8081/joboverview

```
{
    "running": [
        {
            "jid": "e4e6edb76b887054d7aca460b7136937",
            "name": "Filter",
            "state": "RUNNING",
            "start-time": 1505971363801,
            "end-time": -1,
            "duration": 11588615,
            "last-modification": 1505971363832,
            "tasks": {
                "total": 1,
                "pending": 0,
                "running": 1,
                "finished": 0,
                "canceling": 0,
                "canceled": 0,
                "failed": 0
            }
        }
    ],
    "finished": [
        {
            "jid": "ec16f4cf01192268150c750966cefd0d",
            "name": "Flink Java Job at Thu Sep 21 10:52:09 IST 2017",
            "state": "FINISHED",
            "start-time": 1505971329989,
            "end-time": 1505971330746,
            "duration": 757,
            "last-modification": 1505971330746,
            "tasks": {
                "total": 3,
                "pending": 0,
                "running": 0,
                "finished": 3,
                "canceling": 0,
                "canceled": 0,
                "failed": 0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Jobs available in History Server**

localhost:8082/joboverview

```
{
    "running": [],
    "finished": [
        {
            "jid": "ec16f4cf01192268150c750966cefd0d",
            "name": "Flink Java Job at Thu Sep 21 10:52:09 IST 2017",
            "state": "FINISHED",
            "start-time": 1505971329989,
            "end-time": 1505971330746,
            "duration": 757,
            "last-modification": 1505971330746,
            "tasks": {
                "total": 3,
                "pending": 0,
                "running": 0,
                "finished": 3,
                "canceling": 0,
                "canceled": 0,
                "failed": 0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Flink History server config :**

```
#==============================================================================
# HistoryServer
#==============================================================================

# The HistoryServer is started and stopped via bin/historyserver.sh (start|stop)

# Directory to upload completed jobs to. Add this directory to the list of
# monitored directories of the HistoryServer as well (see below).
jobmanager.archive.fs.dir: hdfs://<hdfs>:8020/sax/flink/jobmanager

# The address under which the web-based HistoryServer listens.
historyserver.web.address: localhost

# The port under which the web-based HistoryServer listens.
historyserver.web.port: 8082

# Comma separated list of directories to monitor for completed jobs.
historyserver.archive.fs.dir: hdfs://<hdfs>:8020/sax/flink/jobmanager

# Interval in milliseconds for refreshing the monitored directories.
historyserver.archive.fs.refresh-interval: 10000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first line of the Flink website you linked states:

> Flink has a history server that can be used to query the **statistics of
>   completed jobs** after the corresponding Flink cluster has been shut
>   down.

which also states that

> The HistoryServer allows you to query the status and statistics of
>   **completed jobs** that have been archived by a JobManager.

Now from what I see, you also have access to the monitoring api which you accessed with "localhost:8081/joboverview", If you want to access only the running jobs you can access them with "/joboverview/running" uri

You can find more information at the [Monitoring API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/rest_api.html) link here.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your reply. Yes I have gone through the document and its clear that only completed jobs will be displayed in history server. I got confused because I compared it with spark history server where we get to see both running and completed jobs. Here in Flink I am able to see the json with running and completed but the running json is always empty. That is the reason I posted this question to clarify my doubts.

Comment: Running is always empty? can you maybe update the question with a bit more information so that we can have a look what exactly is wrong. Otherwise, if the answer helped you, you can mark it as accepted.